# How does a Redis slave stay in sync after the replication is over?

Tags: redis

Redis's [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) starts upon connection of a slave to the master. But after the inital replication is over, how does the slave continuously stay in sync with the master? I could not find any part of the documentation describing this mechanism. In particular, how can I measure the lag between the master and the slave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the initial replication, the master writes changes to internal buffers and sends them to the slave(s). From the [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) page:

> The master will then send to the slave all buffered commands. This is
>   done as a stream of commands and is in the same format of the Redis
>   protocol itself.

You can look at the [full replication source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.0/src/replication.c) (this points to Redis version 3.0) on GitHub for the nitty-gritty details.

As far as latency is concerned, there is a [page dedicated to latency troubleshooting](http://redis.io/topics/latency) and [one dedicated to latency monitoring](http://redis.io/topics/latency-monitor). These two pages contain a plethora of background information and techniques to troubleshoot/measure Redis latency. A simple place to start is by running `redis-cli --latency -h 'host' -p 'port'` from slave to master and/or master to slave.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find that out by doing issuing `INFO replication` on the slave and examining the value of `slave_repl_offset`.

Comment: that is incorrect. slave_repl_offset is not the offset from the master, but rather how far along the slave is. The only way to calculate the lag here is to subtract slave_repl_offset from master_repl_offset on the master (not the slave)
an explanation can be found here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2375